# How to print a variable in a tkinter label using python

Tags: python-3.x, bash, shell, tkinter

I would like to print a label "Camera is loaded" in tkinter from variable, if kernel load camera. When text in gnome-terminal "lsmod |grep uvcvideo" show if camera is load in kernel. I would like to do the same in python with tkinter. Below my code show only the window. Can anyone help me ?

CODE:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
import subprocess
import os

root = Tk()
root.title('Camera')
root.geometry("330x166")

var = StringVar()
var.set(os.system("lsmod |grep uvcvideo"))

l = Label(root, textvariable = var)
l.pack()

def NewFile():
    print("New File!")

def OpenFile():
    name = askopenfilename()
    print(name)

def About():
    print("This simple program written by me.")

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
filemenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=NewFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open...", command=OpenFile)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)

helpmenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
helpmenu.add_command(label="About...", command=About)

#root.after(10000, root.destroy)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try `var.set('Camera is loaded' if os.system('lsmod | grep ^uvcvideo') == 0 else '')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you are missing is that `os.system` does not return the command output, but rather

> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process (...)

So in order for your example to work, you'd need something like:

```py
var = StringVar()
exit_code = os.system("lsmod |grep uvcvideo")
message = f"Camera is {'loaded' if exit_code == 0 else 'not loaded'}"
var.set(message)
```

Because 0 exit code implies that the process finished successfully. Although for that I'd check the exit codes for `grep` and `lsmod` to be sure.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate that.

Comment: How do I change color if result is loaded and direffernt color if result is not loaded?

Comment: that's an entire different question, but it's not hard to find; almost all tkinter widgets have a 'foreground' or 'fg' keyword available in config, i.e. `Label(root, text="foo", fg="green")`.